# REST Design: Adding/Deleting a related entity from a given entity using REST

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, restful-architecture

Let's suppose I have an Group of users and I want to add/delete users from the group. What I am confused about is what will be the best practice to design the urls. Here are the options

OPTION # 1

> POST /groups/{groupId}/users -- The request body will contain the userId
>   DELETE /groups/{groupId}/users/{userId} -- The userId will be in the path and the request body will be empty

OPTION # 2

> DELETE /groups/{groupId}/users -- The request body will contain the userId
>   POST /groups/{groupId}/users/{userId} -- The userId will be in the path and the request body will be empty

I believe both the answers are correct and I am guessing there is no right or wrong answer here, just personal preference.But I would like to know what is used wide-spread. I have been using OPTION # 1 because I read in some book (the name escapes me) that the data you are `POST`ing shouldn't be a part of the `url` while using `DELETE` there is no such best-practice restraint.

All inputs appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option 1 seems to be the most common one. I don't have the feeling that the option 2 is valid at all!

Comment: thanks for the input! Do you think option # 1 is still valid even though the only content in the request body is the user's id?

Comment: you don't need to put anything in the request body when sending a `DELETE` request, since the request URI already contains the `userId`. Only `POST` and `PUT` request should have a request body.

Comment: @xmenymenzmen You are not allowed by the HTTPbis spec to use the body of DELETE request. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-25#page-29

Comment: Being the most common doesn't mean it's correct. Option #2 is valid and correct.

Answer (score 3):

The first option is the most common, but that means nothing, since misconceptions about REST are widespread. As a matter of fact, #1 isn't REST at all, it's RPC pure and simple.

Adding a member to the collection can be done either through a `POST` to the collection `/groups/{groupId}/users`, with the location of the created resource returned in the `Location` response header, or through a `PUT` request to the final location `/groups/{groupId}/users/{userId}`. The `POST` should return a `201 Created` response, and the `PUT` either that or `200 OK`, if the resource already existed and was replaced by the new one.

To delete, the correct way is to use `DELETE /groups/{groupId}/users/{userId}`. It's not a matter of personal preference. `POST` is a method you use for operations that aren't standardized by the HTTP protocol. Simple deletion is standardized through the `DELETE` method. Implementing it through the `POST` method simply means you'll have to document that functionality, instead of relying on the standard itself. You'd use `POST` only if you are doing something fancy during the deletion, something that already requires the functionality to be documented.